# Unhandled exception: Stack Overflow -dart

Tags: dart, methods, getter, setter, unhandled-exception

```dart
    class Rectangle {
     double left, top, width, height;

     Rectangle(this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);

     // Define two calculated properties: right and bottom.
     double get right => left + width;
     set right(double value) => left = value - width;
     double get bottom => top + height;
     set bottom(double value) => top = value - height;

     var rect = Rectangle(3, 4, 20, 15);
    }
```

Comment: Each `Rectangle` instance has a `rect` member that creates another `Rectangle` instance that has a `rect` member that creates another `Rectangle` instance that has a `rect` member that creates another `Rectangle` instance.... Why is `rect` a member of `Rectangle`?

Comment: hey thank you , i solved it when i use var rec in the void main (){var rect = Rectangle(3, 4, 20, 15);} not in the same class,thank you so much